# React Native - Does a modal with visible=false affect performance?

Tags: react-native, performance, react-native-modal

Like the title said, If I have many modals with `visible={false}` from the moment user enter the screen until they exit the screen, will that affect performance comparing not having them? Will those modals do some render before hand and therefore affect the first time loading the screen?

Comment: well it depends. if the modal component is itself wrapped within if else statement and the value is `false` then it wont load at all. this can be a bit of an improvement in performance. but if the modal is not wrapped around such statement, it will load the modal component. maybe it wont show the modal, but if there are any functions or effects that run directly when the modal component loads, then those effects and functions will run even though the modal is not visible

Comment: by modal component itself wrapped within if else statement i mean something like `{showModal && <Modal />}`